# Not showing 0 counts in Pandas category frequency tables

Tags: python, pandas, categories, frequency, categorical-data

I am using the following Python code to analyze the number of levels a categorical variable has, and delete variables that have more than 53 levels:

```
df.select_dtypes(['category']).apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
```

I receive the following output:

```
Out[1]:
favorite_drink         35
sex                     2
title                  12
status                  3
dtype: int64
```

I see that the variable title has 12 levels. I want to analyze the value of those 12 levels, so I use:

```
df['title'].value_counts()
```

And I receive hundreds and hundres of lines through the output of previous values of the variable `title` that right now have frequency 0. I am showing just a summary for illustrative purposes:

```
Out [2]:
...
361xx                          0
460xx                          0
178xx                          0
607xx                          0
Name: title, dtype: int64
```

What I would like to do is, that `value_counts()` function only showed me the frequency of values that have frequency above 0. I know `np.nan` values have argument `dropna = False`, but I haven´t seen one for null frequency. I believe this topic is treated [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8559) without a solution from `pandas`.

The `dtypes` of my variables are:

```
df.dtypes

Out[3]:
favorite_drink            category
sex                       category
title                     category
status                    category
```

Thanks in advance for your help on an approach to this necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply filter your series:

```
c = df['title'].value_counts()
c = c[c > 0]
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp for your fast response. R user moving to Python here. I have used your answer to modifiy my code and printing: print(df[col].value_counts()[df[col].value_counts()>0]) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NuValue, Sure - the reason I split it in 2 lines is so that you don't calculate `value_counts` twice unnecessarily. Of course, you *can* do this one line as you've done.